# Jquery function does not display animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created two functions which will allow me to use them with different CSS classes.

```
    var CSSElement;
$(document).ready(function(){  


  expandBox (".orange");
  minimizeBox(".orange");

});

function expandBox ($CSSElement){
     //When mouse rolls over  
    $($CSSElement).mouseover(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'485px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
    });     
}

function minimizeBox ($CSSElement){
     //When mouse is removed  
    $(CSSElement).mouseout(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
    }); 
}
```

However, only the function expandBox seems to work. If I hover my mouse away the from the .orange element the box does not contract.

I want these animations to appear as functions as I plan to use them few times within my website. If I put my code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

   //When mouse rolls over  
    $($CSSElement).mouseover(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'485px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
    });  

  //When mouse is removed  
    $(CSSElement).mouseout(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
    }); 

});
```

Everything seems to work ok. Is there a reason why the first code does not work but the second one does?

Thanks,

vnayak

Comment: Could you please provide complete set of information, i.e. HTML and jQuery parts, and also encapsulate it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you made a typo :

```
$($CSSElement)

$(CSSElement)
```

thats why it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks Kitty! It works perfectly now. Late night coding is a bad thing for me, I guess!

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `$` is a perfectly legal character in identifiers (rather than, say, completely forbidden [like in C] or a special sigil [PHP, Perl]). As a result, `$CSSElement` is a different identifier to `CSSElement` - if only one is defined, the other won't work. *`$($CSSElement)` and `$(CSSElement)` are different*.

(It is potentially confusing to prefix variable names with `$`; in JavaScript they work just fine without.)

What is happening here:

1. Both functions take a parameter named with `$`.
2. `expandBox` uses that parameter with the `$`.
3. `minimizeBox` uses it *without* the `$` (thus using some unrelated variable).

My advice: Change everything to not use prefixed `$`, like this:

```
function expandBox (CSSElement){
     //When mouse rolls over  
    $(CSSElement).mouseover(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'485px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
    });     
}

function minimizeBox (CSSElement){
     //When mouse is removed  
    $(CSSElement).mouseout(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})  
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Michaelb958. Much appreciated.